# Android UI onto TV - Looks Terrible

Tags: android, user-interface, dpi, television

hoping someone can guide me here

I've got an app that looks nice on the phone, but we need to be able to connect and mirror the phone to a TV.  I have the adapters and cables and I can hook the phone to the TV and all of that part works.

but when the app launches on the TV - the UI looks TERRIBLE

the images are stretched or missing
the text is stretched too tall

the TV is 1920 x 1080 - just like the phone - but obviously less dense

And I can't figure out what I need to do to get this UI to look correct on the TV

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Comment: `Can anyone point me in the right direction?` how ? you've posted absolutely no code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created a layout variation for TVs?

1. Click on the "Orientation for Preview" button in the layout editor [(number 2 in this bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvs60.png)
2. Click "Create Other..."
3. Select "UI Mode" as a qualifier, then select "Television" in the dropdown
4. Design your layout. You may need to change the "Device for Preview" (number 3 in the bar) to a TV

Your layout folder will look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fuPg.png), and your app should automatically use the television layout when it's on the TV